# Where can one buy a new physical copy of a full (OT & NT) Protestant RSV where its NT is of '71?

Tags: bible-translation

And are they even being printed nowadays? I have looked around and mostly found Catholic editions and some others, but not a Protestant '71 version.

Is there even one available with cross references?

Comment: I think that in the protestant world the RSV is generally regarded as being superceded by the ESV. Might be why you're finding it so hard to acquire an older version (they probably aren't in print any more)

Answer (score 1):

[*The New Oxford Annotated Bible*](http://amzn.to/2nIrcpY) contains the 1971 RSV New Testament text (not the RSVCE).  As far as I know it is still in print - and available on Amazon.

It does contain the Deuterocanonical books set off in an appendix and labeled as "Apocrypha".